# mvc controller pameter getting null value in ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am making ajax call like this

```
 deleteAge(item: any): string {

           $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'DeleteAge',
                data: item.Id(),
                success: (response) => {
                    toastr.success("ready soon");
                },
                error: (event) => {
                    toastr.error("Error occured ");
                }
            }).always(() => {

                });


        return "";


    }
```

Here is my method in controller which is currently nothing almost implemented

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteAge(string id)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

when i run the code then in my controller i dont get any id.. its null. when i debug my javascript code then this code `item.Id()` is not blank. Even if i pass hardcoded value to data in ajax call still controller gets null. What is wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use `{ id: item.Id()},` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using:

```
data: item.Id(),
```

I'd suggest using:

```
data: { id: item.Id()},
```

This way the id value is associated with the `id` name - allowing model binding to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameters like `json` format in `ajax`

replace `data: item.Id() with data: {id: 1}`